# Seo Friendly URL with Rewrite

Tags: php, iis, url-rewriting

I have a links on my site like;

campaigns.php AND product.php?id=5

After some research, i have converted them to;

campaigns AND product?id=5

With this 2 rule:

```
            <rules>
                <rule name="hide.php" enabled="false">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php" matchType="IsFile" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.php" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="redirecting.php" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*).php$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*).php$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
```

But they are not enough, i want to convert them to;

if possible;

product/name/productname

if not;

product/id/5 will be enough.

ALSO, i need to exclude NTK folder from this rewrite engine.

Comment: A simple mod rewrite should get you sorted. Read up here: https://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/

Comment: Is this IIS? because it looks like it. You need to specify the type of server you're using. They do not work the same and it does not use htaccess

Comment: @PanamaJack Yes it is IIS 8 Microsoft server 2012